# Identical routes beneath Rails constraints causing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have two modules of controllers (which extend a base set of controllers, as they share significant portions of code).

My routes file currently looks like this:

```
  constraints(!Subdomain) do
    scope :module => "standalone" do
      namespace "account" do
        resources :questionnaires, :only => :index do
            resources :responses, :except => :new do
                member do
                    get 'save'
                end
                resources :questions, :only => [:index, :show] do
                    resources :answers, :only => [:index, :show] do
                        resource :choice, :only => [:create]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  constraints(Subdomain) do
    scope :module => "organise" do
      namespace "account" do
        resources :questionnaires, :only => :index do
            resources :responses, :except => :new do
                member do
                    get 'save'
                end
                resources :questions, :only => [:index, :show] do
                    resources :answers, :only => [:index, :show] do
                        resource :choice, :only => [:create]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
      end
      namespace "admin" do
        resources :questionnaires, :only => :index do
          resources :responses, :only => [:index, :show]
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This all looked fine, except that both sets of routes still seem to be parsed and one set will override the other - generating path helpers for only one set. Here's a split list of the routes generated: http://pastie.org/private/nhvmokit7y0dwywqtdlq (it's quite large and you might need to put it in a text editor to read more easily).

As you can see it doesn't generate the helpers for the second set of routes. It also doesn't seem to recognise them correctly when navigating the site either.

Has anyone experienced this before, or know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

After discussing this with a few people I figured the easiest way to work around this problem was instead to use shallow-nested controllers and rely more on permissions to control what a user can see.